# How to use the WinRM C++ API in a simple example

Tags: c++, winrm

why is my code failing to run a simple executable using [WinRM's C++ API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/winrm-c---api)?

```
//main.cpp
int main()
{
    ShellClient *shellClient = new ShellClient();
    
    //Set up the shell client here and connect to the localhost.
    //This seems to be working fine because I'm handling every
    //possible error code, and none of them are being triggered
    
    PCWSTR commandLine = L"\"MyExampleExecutable.exe\"";
    isOk = shellClient->RunCommand(commandLine);
    
    if (!isOk)
        return 1;
        
    return 0;   
}

//ShellClient.cpp
bool ShellClient::RunCommand(PCWSTR command)
{
    WSMAN_SHELL_ASYNC createCommandAsync;
    ZeroMemory(&createCommandAsync, sizeof(createCommandAsync));
    createCommandAsync.operationContext = this;
    createCommandAsync.completionFunction = (WSMAN_SHELL_COMPLETION_FUNCTION)CommandCreatedCallback;
    
    WSManRunShellCommand(shellHandle, 0, command, NULL, NULL, &createCommandAsync, &commandHandle);
    
    if (commandHandle == NULL)//It is *always* NULL
    {
        std::cout << "command handle null" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

One possible clue is that my C++ code thinks the shell gets created fine, but in the Event Viewer for my machine, there is this:

```
WSMan operation CreateShell failed, error code 2150859250
```

At the time of writing, this lovely error code gives precisely zero results when put into Google, making it rather difficult to know what it means.

**Background and common solutions which I have already checked**

As documented [here](https://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/understanding-and-troubleshooting-winrm-connection-and-authentication-a-thrill-seekers-guide-to-adventure) and explaned in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aI4aVS-25Rw) by the same author, most WinRM issues boil down to either connection or authentication problems. In my case, if I deliberately enter incorrect user credentials, I get an authentication error, so I know that my program is connecting *and* authenticating fine when the correct username and password are supplied. Also:

- From the command line, I can connect to my local machine and pretend it's a remote server, for example the following command works fine:

```
    winrs -r:http://localhost:5985 -u:COMPUTERNAME\Jeremy "dir"
```

- `winrm quickconfig` shows the service is working (which we already know otherwise the `winrs` command wouldn't work)
- `winrm get winrm/config` shows `TrustedHosts = localhost`, `AllowUnencrypted = true`, and all authentication methods are set to true
- Following [this advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/authentication-for-remote-connections#negotiate-authentication), I have set the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy = 1`
- Working in Windows 10

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of this so can't comment on whether it's common knowledge but Microsoft have a nifty [error lookup tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool) where you can enter an error code (after converting it from a normal number to hexadecimal) and it tells you what it means.

In this case, `2150859250` (`803381F2` in hex) corresponds to:

```
  ERROR_WINRS_IDLETIMEOUT_OUTOFBOUNDS                            wsmerror.h
# The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The
# requested IdleTimeout is outside the allowed range.
```

When setting up the WinRM shell, I was doing the following:

```
    WSMAN_SHELL_STARTUP_INFO  startupInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.idleTimeoutMs = 1000;//not large enough!
    startupInfo.workingDirectory = L"C:\\";
    //other parameters of startupInfo set here

    WSManCreateShell(session, 0, shellUri, &startupInfo, NULL, NULL, &createShellAsync, &shellHandle);
```

Changing `idleTimeoutMs` from 1000 to a much larger number like 100000 solved the error and my program now works fine.

Since the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wsman/ns-wsman-wsman_shell_startup_info_v10) for this parameter say anything between 0 and 0xFFFFFFFF are valid, it remains a mystery why a value of 1000 is throwing this error. I leave this for somebody more knowledgable than myself to answer, on the off chance that they come across this question.